# 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController version issue with Wix Installer and .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, wix, windows-services

I get an exception "Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController, Version=4.2.3.0" when trying to install a Windows Service written in .Net Core 3.1 using Wix 3.11.2. The version of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll on my system is 4.7.19.56404. I've added the ..\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0 directory per one suggestion and also enabled AutoGenerateBindingRedirects and GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType in the project file. How to work around this binding issue?

Comment: Can you point me to how to create such a service? I'm in VS2019 and I only see a .NET Framework Windows Service project type. Are you creating a "Worker Service"?

Comment: are you following this? https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/

Comment: I don't have an answer but I can say I followed the directions in the link above and it all worked fine.  The 4.700.19.56404 is what I saw come along.

Comment: I have an opensource WiX tool called IsWiX that has tutorials here. https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials   For .net core it's basically the same as the Windows Service example but instead of the xcopy postbuild command you use the PublishProfile pattern like found in the WebApp.  The other difference is you edit the profile to have your dotnet publish settings you want.

Comment: Maybe looking at the code here https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/worker-service   will help you solve your problem.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - I created the service by starting with Core 3.1 Web Api template, then added Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices nuget package to my project and then appending `.UseWindowsService()` to the `CreateDefaultBuilder` method in Program.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by first using publish to generate the output files, and then added them as components to my `Product.wxs` file. Then the service installed and ran fine. It was a lot of files so I wrote a small console app to generate the component XML to a file and pasted that into the `Product.wxs` file.

Initially, I was taking the files from the folder upstream from the publish folder. I may also have overlooked a file as well because I was adding them manually.